# Saving Word document as PDF

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

This is related to converting a Word document to PDF format.

I get an error in my Excel VBA code.

> Run-time error "5": Invalid procedure call or argument

Saving into a Word document works

```
objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs PathName & NewFileName & ".docx"
```

The below runs but it creates a PDF document which is very big in size.

```
objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:=PathName & NewFileName & ".pdf", _ 
  FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
```

I recorded a macro in Word to save the file as PDF and modified the generated code as per below.

```
objWord.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
  PathName & NewFileName & ".pdf", _
  ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
  wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
  Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
  CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
  BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
```

I am using Excel VBA to do a Mailmerge using Word document and it is working fine and able to save individual documents in Word format but I need to save it in PDF format.

Comment: In which line of code you are getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it does save it in the same folder as where the word documents are stored but it works.

```
    Private Sub Knop2_Click()
 Dim directory As String
 Dim enddirectory As String
 
    directory = "C:\docs" ' The starting directory
    enddirectory = "C:\pdf" 'einde
  
    Dim fso, newFile, folder, files
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(directory)
    Set files = folder.files
    
    For Each file In files
    

        Dim newName As String
        newName = Replace(file.Path, ".doc", ".pdf")
        newName = Replace(file.Path, ".docx", ".pdf")
        
        Documents.Open FileName:=file.Path, _
            ConfirmConversions:=False, ReadOnly:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
            PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, _
            WritePasswordDocument:="", WritePasswordTemplate:="", Format:= _
            wdOpenFormatAuto, XMLTransform:=""
            
        ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=newName, _
            ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
            wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
            Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
            CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
            BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False

        ActiveDocument.Close
        
      
    Next

End Sub
```